# Trying to print a range of Fibonacci numbers in C

Tags: c, fibonacci

The following is an attempt to print a number of fibonacci sequence numbers, determined by the user. Uses a user-define function, fibonacci(int a). It is printing the wrong output, not a recursive sequence, but a continually doubling sequence. How can the code be fixed so that it works correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int a);
void main()
{
    int number, range;
    printf("Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &range);
    number = fibonacci(range);
    printf("%d\n", number);
}

int fibonacci(int a)
{
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 1;
    int position;
    if (a == 1)
    {
        printf("%d", num1);
    }
    if (a == 2)
    {
        printf("%d\n", num1);
        printf("%d", num2);
    }
    if (a > 2)
    {
        for(position = 1; a >= position; position++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", num1);
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = num1 + num2;
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the following output for all numbers:

```
1
1
2
4
8
16
...
```

The desired output is the fibonnaci sequence (each number is the sum of the two previous ones):

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
...
```

Comment: So, what's your question? We need a more specific error statement in order to help.

Comment: `if (a = 2)` => `if (a == 2)`. Same for `(a = 1)`

Comment: `=` and `==` are different operators. If you don't get a warning about this, you probably don't have enough warnings enabled. (If you do get a warning, don't ignore it but fix your code.) Also, you are not printing any space or newlines between the numbers, except for the one place that has `\n`, so you can't tell the difference between 11 and two 1's.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh. This definitely helps, but it leaves me with a list of doubling numbers.

Comment: There is not a question here.  I have no idea what you want.

Comment: @abelenky I have added more explanation and a question. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: google "fibonacci algorithm"

Comment: `num1 = num2; num2 = num1 + num2;` is basically the same thing as `num2 = num2 + num2;`. Any more questions?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The algorithms used present material more complex than what I have learned. I would like to keep the structure of the code, without the added complexity.

Comment: "Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers: 14
1
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
14"

Comment: The trailing `14` is because you are missing the return statement from your function, which should also produce a warning.

Comment: Also, the type of `main` should be `int main`, not `void main`. If you are following a book or tutorial that has `void main`, throw it away. If your compiler doesn't warn you about these things, get a compiler that does, and don't even run your code until you have understood and fixed every warning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that within the loop you first *overwrite* `num1` by assigning `num2` to it:

```
num1 = num2;
```

Then you make `num2` be the sum of itself and `num1`, but you have just made `num1` equal to `num2`, so this line is effectively just multiplying `num2` by two (i.e., adding it to itself):

```
num2 = num1 + num2;
```

You need to preserve the old value and use that for the sum, e.g., by adding a third, temporary, variable.

(Apart from this, you also have various other problems, but all of them are such that they should produce compiler warnings. If they don't, enable all warnings and/or get a better compiler. Once you get warnings, don't ignore them but research the cause for each of them and fix all warnings before you even run your code.)

Comment: How exactly would this work? I tried and utterly failed.

Comment: @caleb132 Well, if you understand how to declare a variable, use that knowledge to add an `int` variable. Then, assign one of the `num` variables to that to store its old value before you assign a new value to it. After that you can easily fix the bug by using the stored old value…